# WebView opens static version of website

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://groupedirectouest.com");
}
}

class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
}
```

when I use ua (userAgent) string, webview shows desktop version of website. 
here is the ua string i have used :

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
```

here is the website that i am trying to open in my

```
http://groupedirectouest.com/
```

it works fine with chrome but webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now there are custom chrome tabs for you!

The WebView is good solution if you are hosting your own content inside your app. If your app directs people to URLs outside your domain,it is now recommended that you use Chrome custom tabs for various benefits.
Follow the link below:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs